# Auctex change default comment style for latex-mode

Tags: init-file, auctex, comment

I want a double `%%` to start my comments in latex documents. I'have found two solutions suggested

```lisp
;; solution 1
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook  '(lambda() (setq comment-start "%% ")))

;; solution 2
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook (lambda () (setq-local comment-add 0)))
```

but both don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Auctex LaTeX mode hook is `LaTeX-mode-hook` (note the capitalization). So try

```el
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook  (lambda() (setq comment-start "%% ")))
```

Note also that `lambda` expressions are self-evaluating so you don't need to quote them in this context.

I am assuming you are using `M-;` to comment things, otherwise `comment-start` does not enter into the equation.

Comment: Thanks, brilliant this works.